Correct way to add PRIVATE_KEY in Glitch .env?
I'm following this document to add PRIVATE_KEY in, https://glitch.com/, in this documentation they mentioned like this,


Click on the file ".env" on the left sidebar, then click on ✏️ Plain text on top. Do not edit it directly from UI as it will break
your key formatting.




Edit it with your private key and passphrase. Make sure a multiline key has the same line breaks like below. Env variables are only
visible to the owner of the Glitch project. Use a separate private key
for testing only, and not your production key.


Below is the code sample they have provided
PASSPHRASE="my-secret"

PRIVATE_KEY="-----[REPLACE THIS] BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIE...
...
...xyz
-----[REPLACE THIS] END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"

So, as in the Documentation, I Added like below,
PRIVATE_KEY=-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,87FC14DC89A1E88F

1mSlTt5heI/noo0wpvwp8P0bqUomF7ehu+NxuNd5BpKh9dZnsUpXVxEI4f3jZCQa
1mSlTt5heI/noo0wpvwp8P0bqUomF7ehu+NxuNd5BpKh9dZnsUpXVxEI4f3jZCQa
..bla bla bla,,
+bg/t1nX7NnA/5OwvJxyOeC7va9HrFpmN8JBDWVjshsBvUcgk2sHCyG0rsepCgVY
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

that looks like this in .env UI
but, when I try to check I the availability,
if (!PRIVATE_KEY) {
    throw new Error(
      'Private key is empty. Please check your env variable "PRIVATE_KEY".'
    );
  }

I'm getting the below error
Error: Private key is empty. Please check your env variable "PRIVATE_KEY".

What went wrong with this? Thanks in Advance


Multi line .env variables need to be escaped

What does it mean? , could you provide any example, how it to be placed?

Does this answer your question? Using multi-line value in .env file in docker-compose
